# Makefile builds target even if prerequisites haven't changed

Tags: makefile

Most makefiles have a structure such as this:

```
.PHONY: prebuild    

all: $(TARGET)

prebuild: Makefile
    $(shell DEPDIR=$(DEPDIR) mkdir -p $(DEPDIR)/../common   >/dev/null)
    # do other work related to preparing for the object files to be built such as run a script to modify a header file included by $(TARGET).c         

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c prebuild
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c
```

The implicit rules know how to build `$(TARGET).o` from `$(TARGET).c`, and doesn't do any work if `$(TARGET).o` is already newer than `$(TARGET).c`. This happens when make is run multiple times without changing the source file.

However, building the `all` target above will seemingly always rerun the `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).c` link to link the application and create the application binary. This happens even if that binary already exists and doesn't need to be recreated. In some larger projects, this process can take a long time (tens of seconds), which is sometimes not desirable.

**Edit #1:** The issue has to do something with an extra phony target that I do want to run ONCE before the object files are built. In my case, I'm running a script which takes Makefile variables and possibly updates a header file that is included in the C file. But, if the Makefile doesn't change, the prebuild target isn't run. However, the `$(TARGET)` target is still run even if `prebuild` doesn't do anything (for instance, because `Makefile` wasn't changed). FYI: because of the structure of my build system, I have `prebuild` run always because my build system is used for a variety of applications that can dynamically redefine `prebuild`.

- How can this Makefile be restructured to not do the linking again when not necessary?

**Edit #2:** 
Here's a simplified example that seems to illustrate my issue:

Before running, create a new directory and `touch a b`

```
.PHONY: prebuild main all

all: main

prebuild: a Makefile
    @echo prebuild ran


main: prebuild 
    @echo main ran
```

When I run, I get this output:

```
prebuild ran
main ran
```

This is what happens no matter how many times I run make, even though the prerequisite a nor Makefile doesn't change. What I expect to happen is prebuild doesn't run (because a and Makefile don't change) and main also doesn't run because prebuild doesn't run. Clearly, I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. What is your version of make, what is `TARGET`?

Comment: `TARGET` is just the name of the binary that ends up being executed. If I didn't specify the `-o` option, `CC` would just create a binary called `a.out`. I'm using GNU make 4.2. Isn't it the case that regardless of the prerequisite state, the application will be linked every time I run make?

Comment: Your example works correctly: if you take this makefile and use it as-is (setting `TARGET` and touching the `.c` file) you'll see it works fine: `make all` does not rebuild every time.  Therefore, this example doesn't correctly reflect your real situation and we can't guess what might be wrong.  Please create a MCVE to show the problem you're having.

Comment: You are right -- I realized the real issue has to do with a phony normal prerequisite. Please see my updated example.

Comment: If `prebuild` and `main` are not real files, then how can Make tell whether `a` and `Makefile` are up to date? It has nothing to compare them to.

Comment: I see. So, now returning to my original example above, with `$(TARGET)`, what I actually want is to always run `prebuild` but only run the linker (that is, the `$(TARGET)` commands) if `$(TARGET).o` changes. Perhaps the `prebuild` can be a dependency of `all` and `$(TARGET)` can only have a single dependency, which is its associated object file. Is that the best solution or are there more recommended approaches?

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear as to what you want but I think you might get closer to your goal if you make `prebuild` an [order only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that extra dependency triggering your rebuild.
Try this:

```
.PHONY: all

OUTPUTDIR=common/
TARGET=finalexe

all: $(OUTPUTDIR)/$(TARGET)

$(OUTPUTDIR)/$(TARGET): $(TARGET).c | $(OUTPUTDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(TARGET).c

$(OUTPUTDIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

In this above example, 'finalexe' will be created if A. it doesn't yet exist or B. if finalexe.c was modified. The timestamp on the OUTPUTDIR is not checked.